# atom julia syntax highlighting

Tags: julia, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

im trying to set up an editor syntax highlighting scheme for julia in atom, (using juno although i do not know if that is relevant).

i have googled around for two hours and tinkered around in atoms' settings and in the https://atom.io/packages/language-julia specific settings too.

i've found mentions about running scripts (juno) https://github.com/JunoLab/Juno.jl/issues/15 etc but i think this is not a solution, a simpler way must exist.

i had expected to be able to find someones stylesheet for julia, adapt it with my preferred colors and plug it into atom...

please, i would be grateful if someone could indicate how to do this: configure colors in editor - syntax highlighting for julia (perhaps with juno). thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you install Juno with Atom the Julia syntax highlighting will just work. Perhaps something did not get installed? Here are the installation instructions that I have tested on lots of students:

- Download and install Atom (available at https://atom.io/).
- Start Atom and press Ctrl + , ( Ctrl  key + comma key ) to open the Atom settings screen.
- Select the Install tab.
- In the Search packages field, type uber-juno and press Enter .
- You will see the uber-juno package developed by JunoLab—click Install to install the package.

However, sometimes the Atom installation gets stalled. In that case you need to stop Atom, delete the `.atom` folder that is usually found in your user home folder and restart Atom. On very rare occasions I also had to reinstall Atom as well.

Finally, note that as of today the recommended IDE for Julia is VS Code and the support for Atom Juno development has stopped.

Comment: thanks, i was actually trying to adapt the existing syntax coloring scheme to my own needs, but could not find the file where to do that. in vs code its called settings.json. maybe ill just stick to vs code? are u sure development has stopped on juno? do you have a link confirming this?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, source: https://github.com/JunoLab/Juno.jl   "Attention: We have decided to join forces with the Julia extension for VSCode. As such, this Atom-based plugin is effectively in “maintenance-only mode” and we expect to only work on bug fixes in the future."